# git repo folder on windows shared by all users

Tags: git

We have a tools folder (d:\tools) on all of our windows servers that we would like to put under source control. We are already using git for other projects. This workflow does not match the normal process of each user having their own repo folder, instead, we need all users on the system to share one folder.

AdminA initialized the folder as a git repo and pushed it to remote (we are using Azure Devops).

But when AdminB tries to make commits and push to remote we get errors.

If git is not the right tool. Could you suggest another source control solution to would meet our requirements?

Comment: Please give details for "we get errors". Also please note that asking for tools is off topic here.

Comment: +1 for "give details for we get errors". Can you also explain what gets versioned under that `tools` repo ? shared scripts that everyone uses on their own machine ? how was it shared / updated until now ?

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to put a *repository* on any kind of shared folder: things go wrong and the repository itself gets corrupted. You can put a *working tree* on a shared folder but this also tends to have things go wrong (recoverably this time but the general theme is "with shared folders, things go wrong": they're not *useless* but shared folders must be treated as Special Snowflakes, not used for everything). Git handles this for you because with Git, *everyone gets a full copy of every commit ever made*. If that's not what you want, you don't want Git.

Comment: I'll recommend also rewrite title: all hosts != all users (each host *may have* more 1 user on it) and your real **business-task** isn't clear now

Answer (score 0):

Follow-up to @torek

- Repository on shared drive is **The Worst Idea (tm)** (especially on Windows-shares)
- Working Tree on shared drive is **The Bad Idea (tm)**
- You have to build not repo per se, but flexible and bullet-proof multi-host deploy tool (which is bigger in common, than "just VCS")

*If* my guesses and reconstruction of a *real business problem are correct*, then below I will give *some possibly useful ideas and considerations*, but **not a complete turnkey solution**.

### Business-task (personal opinion and POV)

A universal and identical set of artifacts on a certain set of hosts that can be changed during operation by some limited (known) set of specialists and approved changes are distributed in real time to all hosts under control

**Clarification required**

- Are these tools binary or text/* (at least mostly)?
- If these tools are binary, do these files are *really big* files?

### Implementation concept

1. One Git repository ("Authoritative source") on the local disk is used on a permanent basis, no shared repository is expected

Git may have git-lfs, if answers on clarifications show "big binaries"

2. Each `d:\tools` is an ordinary folder, which (re)generated by *some Deploy Tool*, initiated by (commit|push) to "Authoritative source"
3. Each member of the Support Team can create (or have) a clone of "Authoritative source", perform needed changes and promote these changes under *personal credentials* into "Authoritative source", which have to run operations from p.2

**Variation**

- It's possible to build a two-tier system of repositories with local clones of "Authoritative source" and `d:\tools` as Working Tree of local clone with restricted possibilities (?) for commit|push on clones

This will

- make it easier to implement Deploy Tool (native Git's push+update), also *somehow faster*

but

- will **complicate and increase** administrative operations for the whole system
- add **multiple possible POF** instead of one